# I want to display output like this with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

this is my original table in database.

| name | qty |
| --- | --- |
| QMORIASDWAD 1 |  |
| QMORIASDWAD 3 |  |
| QMORIASDWAD 4 |  |
| QMORIASDWAD 5 |  |
| QMORIASDWAD 6 |  |
| QMORIASDWAD 7 |  |
| QMORIASDWAD 8 |  |

and I want my result output with select to be like this.

| name | qty |
| --- | --- |
| qm2 | 1 |
| qm2 | 3 |
| qm2 | 4 |
| qm2 | 5 |
| qm2 | 6 |
| qm2 | 7 |
| qm2 | 8 |

Comment: what is the logic here ?

Comment: it's just select logic, can i use case clause?

Comment: this is my original querry
SELECT DISTINCT name, qty
  FROM db
                WHERE     cast (prod_date AS DATE) = cast (getdate () AS DATE) and name <> 'asd'
                     ORDER BY name,qty

Comment: What is the logic to change `QMORIASDWAD` into `qm2` ?

Comment: just change the output when i select my data become the result i want

Comment: No. We are asking what is the **logic** to select 'qm2' instead of 'QMORIASDWAD'. Do you just want a constant 'qm2', regardless of what the row contains? Or is it 'qm', because 'QMORIASDWAD' starts with 'QM'? But what would the '2'come from then? What would be the output, if a row didn't have 'QMORIASDWAD', but 'ABCDEFGHIJK'  forinstance?

Comment: `SELECT 'qm2' as name, qty FROM MyTable` will give you that output. You can try that and come back with some clarification about what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable(
   name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,qty  INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO yourtable(name,qty) VALUES 
('QMORIASDWAD',1),
('QMORIASDWAD',3),
('QMORIASDWAD',4),
('QMORIASDWAD',5),
('QMORIASDWAD',6),
('QMORIASDWAD',7),
('QMORIASDWAD',8);
```

Just use `Concat`,`Lower` and `Left` function

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(LOWER(left(name,2)),2) name,
qty 
FROM YourTable
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xq1BeuVt)

Based on your query,you can use `with`

```
with t as (
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT name, 
    qty 
  FROM 
    db 
  WHERE 
    cast (prod_date AS DATE) = cast (
      getdate () AS DATE
    ) 
    and name <> 'asd'
) 

SELECT 
CONCAT (LOWER(left(NAME, 2)),2) NAME
,qty
FROM t
```